# Replacing values in array which are received as argument of a method

Tags: javascript

In this array children array can have more childrens. I have a method in which I will get "lowValue" and "highValue". "Id" will be unique. when my method get called I need to use this unique id and replace old values of "lowValue" and "highValue" with the new ones. How can I do that?

```js
// put your code here
```

```html
<script>
  myData = [{
      "data": {
        "name": "Applications",
        "size": "200mb",
        "type": "Folder"
      },
      "children": [{
          "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "editor.app",
            "highValue": 20,
            "ratingID": 0,
            "lowValue": 10,
          }
        },
        {
          "data": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "settings.app",
            "highValue": 20,
            "ratingID": 0,
            "lowValue": 10,
            "mappedPersonaCount": 0,
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "name": "Cloud",
        "size": "20mb",
        "type": "Folder"
      },
      "children": [{
        "data": {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "backup-1.zip",
          "highValue": 20,
          "ratingID": 0,
          "lowValue": 10
        }
      }]
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add your attempt to the code panel and give us an example output

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```js
const data = your_original_data
function replacer(lowValue, highValue, id){
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < data[i].children.length; j++){
      if(data[i].children[j].data.id === id){
        data[i].children[j].data.lowValue = lowValue
        data[i].children[j].data.highValue = highValue
        return
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the below-mentioned assumptions:

1. All children where `id` matches the supplied value will have the `lowValue` and `highValue` replaced.
2. The supplied `id` will always be present in the `myData` array in one or more `children`.

the following is one possible solution to achieve the desired result:

```
const replaceValues = (id = 5, lv = 5, hv = 50, arr = myData) => (
  arr.reduce((f, i) => [...f, {
    ...i,
    children: i.children.map(
      child => ({
        ...child,
        data: {
          ...child.data,
          ...(
            child.data.id === id ? {
              lowValue: lv,
              highValue: hv
            } : {}
          )
        }
      })
    )
  }], [])
);
```

**Explanation / Approach**

- The outer `.reduce` helps to iterate through the `myData` array
- Each element in this array is placed as-is (using the `...` spread operator)
- Next, the `children` prop of each `myData` element is specified
- Within this, `i.children` array is iterated using `map` to access each element
- Each element here (again) is placed as-is using the `...` spread-operator
- Next, `data` is specified
- Values for the `data` object are also spread (as before)
- Then, if the `data.id` matches the parameter `id` then, `lowValue` and `highValue` are updated (using parameters `lv` and `hv`, respectively)
- The `...( some_condition ? {k: v} : {} )` is one way to update an object's specific prop/s only when `some_condition` is true

Please use comments below to ask for further clarification/s.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const myData = [{
    "data": {
      "name": "Applications",
      "size": "200mb",
      "type": "Folder"
    },
    "children": [{
        "data": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "editor.app",
          "highValue": 20,
          "ratingID": 0,
          "lowValue": 10,
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "settings.app",
          "highValue": 20,
          "ratingID": 0,
          "lowValue": 10,
          "mappedPersonaCount": 0,
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "name": "Cloud",
      "size": "20mb",
      "type": "Folder"
    },
    "children": [{
      "data": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "backup-1.zip",
        "highValue": 20,
        "ratingID": 0,
        "lowValue": 10
      }
    }]
  }
];

const replaceValues = (id = 5, lv = 5, hv = 50, arr = myData) => arr.reduce((f, i) => [...f, {
  ...i,
  children: i.children.map(
    child => ({
      ...child,
      data: {
        ...child.data,
        ...(
          child.data.id === id ? {
            lowValue: lv,
            highValue: hv
          } : {}
        )
      }
    })
  )
}], []);

console.log('replace id: 5, low: 5, high: 50', replaceValues());
console.log('replace id: 1, low: 11, high: 21', replaceValues(1, 11, 21));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const myData = [{
        "data": {
            "name": "Applications",
            "size": "200mb",
            "type": "Folder"
        },
        "children": [{
                "data": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "editor.app",
                    "highValue": 20,
                    "ratingID": 0,
                    "lowValue": 10,
                }
            },
            {
                "data": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "settings.app",
                    "highValue": 20,
                    "ratingID": 0,
                    "lowValue": 10,
                    "mappedPersonaCount": 0,
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "name": "Cloud",
            "size": "20mb",
            "type": "Folder"
        },
        "children": [{
            "data": {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "backup-1.zip",
                "highValue": 20,
                "ratingID": 0,
                "lowValue": 10
            }
        }]
    }
]

const indexMap = new Map()

const parseDataToMap = (data = []) => {
    data.forEach(e => {
        if (e.children) {
            e.children.forEach(e => {
                indexMap.set(e.data.id, e.data)
            })
        }
    })
}

parseDataToMap(myData)

console.log(myData[0].children[0].data)
const o = indexMap.get(1)
o.highValue = 25
o.lowValue = 11
console.log(myData[0].children[0].data)
```